# PrestaShop - Getting errors after changing the PHP version of our hosting (PS 1.7.5.)

Tags: prestashop

We changed the hosting version from PHP 7.0 to 7.3 yesterday and right after that our website www.bofast.cz stopped working and a few errors have appeared. We went back to the version 7.0 but It did not help. This is the error we are getting:

```
(1/1) ClassNotFoundException

Attempted to load class "Repository" from namespace "PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Cldr".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Cldr\Repository", "PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Localization\Currency\Repository" or "PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Localization\Locale\Repository"?

in Tools.php line 724
at ToolsCore::getCldr(object(Context))

in Currency.php line 101
at CurrencyCore->__construct('1')

in Currency.php line 614
at CurrencyCore::getCurrencyInstance('1')

in Tools.php line 685
at ToolsCore::setCurrency(object(Cookie))

in FrontController.php line 350
at FrontControllerCore->init()

in Controller.php line 262
at ControllerCore->run()

in Dispatcher.php line 511
at DispatcherCore->dispatch()

in index.php line 28
```

Comment: I uploaded the error page here (if that's better to understand) > [link](https://www.bofast.cz/testing/error.html)

Comment: was your problem solved? your website is currently up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear all Prestashop cache from within Advanced Preferences -> Performance tab after reverting? If not, please do this.
Alternatively, remove the var/cache directory and let PS recreate it.

Comment: You're making it sound like a question for clarification.

Comment: Your answer popped up as a "this should probably be deleted". I think maybe it would be better if you phrase it as an answer :)